# SQL Filter Query Hangs with No Response

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

```
SELECT users.id 
FROM orders, users, "userEmailCollections", "reviewTracks", "loyaltyCampaignRedemptions" 
WHERE (orders."restaurantTableId" IN (12,7,9,8,10,11,14,99,100,6) 
AND users.id = orders."orderUserId") 
OR ("userEmailCollections"."restaurantId" = 6 
AND   "userEmailCollections"."userId" = users.id) 
OR ("reviewTracks"."restaurantId" = 6 
AND users.email = "reviewTracks"."email") 
OR ("loyaltyCampaignRedemptions"."restaurantId" = 6 
AND "users".id = "loyaltyCampaignRedemptions"."userId");
```

I'm trying to run the above query to get me all the user ids for users which have relationships with any of the other tables - so for example if a user has an `order`, or a `userEmailCollection` I would like their id to show up in the query output.

However, this query hangs without producing a response and I'm not sure why.

Comment: It looks like a cartesian join, so ... well that's that. There might be 50 billion results to crunch through here and that takes a long time.

Comment: is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I would try to rewrite this query to use union all/union

Comment: I would back up and start smaller. See how much data you are getting back when you join orders and users, then do the same for orders and EmailCollections. Put things back together when you have a better idea of what's actually going on with the different joins in this query. So many tables, so little join criteria, so many OR's ... its not easy to look at this and suggest a solution, but if you are creating cartesian joins then the answer is don't do that.

Comment: @Sergey so just UNION the smaller select queries into one at the end?

Comment: Also, learn to use ansi sql join syntax which makes the logic much clearer to understand and debug. The join syntax you are using hasn’t been considered good practice for 30+ years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select u.id
from users u
join orders ord on u.id=ord."orderUserId"
where ord."restaurantTableId" IN (12,7,9,8,10,11,14,99,100,6) 
union
select u.id
from users u
join "userEmailCollections" col on u.id=col."userId"
where col."restaurantId" = 6 
union 
select u.id
from users u
join "reviewTracks" rev on u.email=rev."email"
where rev."restaurantId" = 6 
union 
select u.id
from users u
join "loyaltyCampaignRedemptions" loyy on u.id=loyy."userId"
where loyy."restaurantId" = 6
```

I would say the query can look something like this

Answer (score 1):

Echoing the above comments....be explicit in the join syntax and break the query into smaller sub queries.  It'll help the db to generate a more efficient execution plan.  for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders ON users.id = orders."orderUserId" AND orders."restaurantTableId" IN (12, 7, 9, 8, 10, 11, 14, 99, 100, 6)
LEFT JOIN "userEmailCollections" ON "userEmailCollections"."userId" = users.id AND "userEmailCollections"."restaurantId" = 6
LEFT JOIN "reviewTracks" ON users.email = "reviewTracks"."email" AND "reviewTracks"."restaurantId" = 6
LEFT JOIN "loyaltyCampaignRedemptions" ON "users".id = "loyaltyCampaignRedemptions"."userId" AND "loyaltyCampaignRedemptions"."restaurantId" = 6;
WHERE orders."orderUserId" IS NOT NULL OR "userEmailCollections"."userId" IS NOT NULL OR "reviewTracks"."email" IS NOT NULL OR "loyaltyCampaignRedemptions"."userId" IS NOT NULL;
```

Here the each cte joins the 2 tables and filters on specific conditions vs a cartesian join.  using distinct will help remove the duplicate rows from the results set.  It's also a bit easier to read and follow.

Comment: This query returns all the user IDs regardless of the contents of the other tables (it's all LEFT JOINs). You reference a CTE in your commentary, but this query doesn't have one. Did you paste in the wrong query?

Comment: @JohnH  I missed the last line.  My thinking is, grab all of the user ids that satisfy the different conditions then use the where clause to limit the return.  They should return the same results as the query you submitted.  I went with the left joins because I'm not entirely sure which subset the OP needs and would rather return results we can parse back than inadvertently limit the return

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to join the tables because the query is about the presence of an association and not the attributes of the associations. The following query should return the desired result in reasonable time:

```
SELECT users.id
  FROM users
 WHERE users.id IN
         (SELECT DISTINCT orders."orderUserId"
           FROM orders
          WHERE orders."restaurantTableId" IN (12, 7, 9, 8, 10, 11, 14, 99, 100, 6))
    OR users.id IN
         (SELECT DISTINCT "userEmailCollections"."userId"
            FROM "userEmailCollections"
           WHERE "userEmailCollections"."restaurantId" = 6)
    OR users.email IN
         (SELECT DISTINCT "reviewTracks"."email"
            FROM "reviewTracks"
           WHERE "reviewTracks"."restaurantId" = 6)
    OR users.id IN
         (SELECT DISTINCT "loyaltyCampaignRedemptions"."userId"
            FROM "loyaltyCampaignRedemptions"
           WHERE "loyaltyCampaignRedemptions"."restaurantId" = 6);
```

DISTINCT is included in the subqueries to improve performance in case there are a large number of duplicate user IDs or emails in the associated tables. Because these are inclusion tests, not using DISTINCT will not change the result set.